# bash script to iterate through file 2 lines at a time and copy needed couplets

Tags: bash, shell-script, cp

The task: using bash, iterate through a file (say, file1.txt), 2 lines at a time, prompting whether each found couplet should be copied to a second file (say, file2.txt). The command `grep -A 1 "searchterm" file1.txt` gives the sort of output I'm looking for. So the script should iterate through each couple of lines, ask whether or not to copy the couplet to a second file, then increment and do the same for the next couple of lines, and so on til the end of the file. The file contains probably around 4000 lines total, maybe 400 or so of which I want to copy to the second file.

Content of the file would look something like the following sample:

```
#searchterm blah
possible additional needed line 1
#searchterm blee
possible additional needed line 2
#searchterm blob
possible additional needed line 3
#searchterm bloh
possible additional needed line 4
#searchterm bluh
possible additional needed line etc
```

Copying to the second file would be done by `cp >>` obviously so as to add it to the end of the file. I think a for loop and/or maybe while might work for this. The incrementing part of it is kind of escaping me at the moment. But my bash scripting skills/knowledge are moderate at best. Input will be appreciated.

**LATER EDIT**
Here's a start toward doing what I'm after (shamelessly pilfered from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314499/read-n-lines-at-a-time-using-bash):

```
while read -r ONE; do
    read -r TWO
    echo $ONE
    echo $TWO
    sleep 3
    # replace above sleep command with command(s) that copy lines or exit back to while loop
done < file1.txt
```

This reads file1.txt two lines at a time, outputting each couplet to the terminal. The sleep 3 line needs to be replaced by some routine that will ask user input such as "Would you like to copy these two lines to file2.txt? Answer y or n." If the user selects y then something like `printf $ONE >>file2.txt && printf $TWO >>file2.txt` gets run before returning to the `while` loop for the next two lines. If the user answers n then the loop just goes back to where it left off, outputting the next two lines of file1.txt to the terminal and asking the same question. Progress?

**Later edit: First failed attempt at a full solution**

```
while read -r ONE; do
    read -r TWO
    echo $ONE
    echo $TWO
    read -n 1 -p "Would you like to copy the above 2 lines to the new  file? [Y,n]" ans
        if [[ $ans == "Y" || $ans == "y" ]]; then
                printf $ONE >>file2.txt && printf $TWO >>file2.txt
        else
                echo "Resuming loop"
        fi
done < file1.txt
```

Doesn't work, meaning its output is not much different than just running `cat file1.txt` from the command line. But maybe it gives a better idea of what I'm hoping to accomplish with the script.

**Yet later edit: semi-operational**
Further research revealed maybe I'd need something called a file descriptor to make this work. Using this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886683/read-stdin-for-user-input-when-a-file-is-already-redirected-to-stdin I modified the script as follows

```
while read -r ONE <&3; do
    read -r TWO <&3
    echo $ONE
    echo $TWO
    read -n 1 -p "Would you like to copy the above 2 lines to the new  file? [Y,n]" ans
        if [[ $ans == "Y" || $ans == "y" ]]; then
                printf $ONE >>file2.txt && printf $TWO >>file2.txt
        else
                echo "Resuming loop"
        fi
done 3<file1.txt
```

This does actually allow me to copy pairs of lines from the file being read to stdin to another file. Pretty much what I want. I just need to puzzle out how to introduce newlines into the file being created so line pairs being copied over to not wind up being on the same line. Further input and explanations welcome.

Comment: "couplet" isn't a common term when talking about searching for strings in files.  Are you saying you want to read two lines from a file, check whether a string appears in either line, and decide whether to write the lines/string to an output file?

Comment: Pretty much that, yeah: copy 2 lines. Although I know that searchterm appears in every other line, in just that form, as in the sample given. Which is why grep -A 1 works to get the 2 lines needed, or couplet. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: The aim is that both the line containing searchterm and the line following get copied to file2.txt

Comment: Does the string to be searched for come from the 2nd `#searchterm xxxx` line?  So the term being searched for changes as the code advances through the file?

Comment: No. searchterm is always the same and appears in the line preceding, but there is some variation in what follows searchterm in the line in which it appears. The second line that is to be included when copying to file2.txt has minor variations in it too. searchterm appears consistently in every other line off the file

Comment: I suggest you start with a `while read` loop, try to write that script and come back with your problem if you don't succeed.

Comment: Do you need to do it in bash? I think awk would be a better option (e.g. `awk '/searchterm/ { getline var; print $0"\n"var > "file2.txt" }' infile`)

Comment: I'm thinking of bash because, though my understanding of it is fairly limited, I do at least have some basic comprehension of its workings. I figured awk would be a choice for this as well, but it's workings are a bit of a black box to me. That said, I'm open to these sorts of suggestions--thanks.

Comment: Testing shows the awk command just blindly copies all matching couplets over the file2.txt, i.e., almost all lines contained in file1.txt. But I need it to offer the user an option of which couplets to copy,. Of the roughly 2000 couplets contained in file1.txt, I only want to copy over maybe 400. So can awk present the option whether to copy or not?

Comment: What is your criteria for "copying over" to a new file? Your example refers to `searchterm` as the starting point of what you want to copy, and then there's some unknown criteria in the second line that makes you decide to copy it over (or not). If you could tease out that second criteria, there's your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the line:

printf $ONE >>file2.txt && printf $TWO >>file2.txt

to

printf "$ONE\n" >>file2.txt && printf "$TWO\n" >>file2.txt

This should put the output of each printf statement on a new line.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
raku -ne 'm/blah | blob/ ?? put($_, "\n", get) !! next;'  

#OR

raku -e 'for lines() { m/blah | blob/ ?? put($_, "\n", get) !! next};'
```

OR

```
raku -e 'for lines.rotor(2) { .join("\n").put if m/blah | blob/ };'

#OR

raku -e 'for lines.batch(2) { .join("\n").put if m/blah | blob/ };'
```

Does it have to be `bash`? Here's an answer written in Raku. Raku's `lines` routine reads input lazily, so it should be pretty efficient. The first two answers return the matching line, then `get`s-and-returns the line that follows each match.

The third answer `rotor`s each couplet together so they're analyzed two-lines-at a time. Since `rotor` drops "incomplete/partial" groupings at the end, the fourth example uses `batch` instead  which returns partial groupings (identical to `rotor(2, partial => True)`).

Sample Input:

```
#searchterm blah
possible additional needed line 1
#searchterm blee
possible additional needed line 2
#searchterm blob
possible additional needed line 3
#searchterm bloh
possible additional needed line 4
#searchterm bluh
possible additional needed line etc
```

Sample Output (all four examples):

```
#searchterm blah
possible additional needed line 1
#searchterm blob
possible additional needed line 3
```

https://raku.org