# How can I print a line matching a text, print the next line, and match again another text in a next line, all this in a text file?

Tags: shell, text-processing

I want to generate a list of Tor exit nodes with IPv6 connectivity by getting their fingerprint (not they IPs because Tor doesn't allows IPv6 addresses to be explicitly chosen).

In the textfile (of Tor) I have lines like this

```
a [2602:fc05::223]:443
m zBBa795v7+KnW1qZP1pK0ZBtxRHQfhHlkJpe/Yh9ok8
s Exit Fast HSDir Running Stable V2Dir Valid
```

What I want to do is to print all the lines of an text file matching a **'['** (denoting an IPv6 address), print the next line (a line with Tor exit node fingerprint), and match again the line next to this having the text **'s Exit'** (to pickup all the Exit nodes). It is for printing lines as I posted above.

How can I do this?

Comment: Related? https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/711543/227738

Comment: Does `sed '/\[/,/^s Exit/!d'` do what you need?

Answer (score 1):

### Perl

```
perl -ne '$f=1 if /\[/; print if $f; $f=0 if /Exit/' infile
```

### Awk

```
awk '/\[/ { f=1 } f { print } /Exit/ { f=0 }' infile
```

Comment: It's almost what you posted, but I want to match '[' and 's Exit' at the same time, I mean match two lines at the same time and also print the line between these two.

Comment: Oh, okay... then it is best described as match everything between delimiters (including lines matching `[` and `Exit`), not so much as the title describes it. Anyway, it would be something like this: `perl -ne '$f=1 if /\[/; print if $f; $f=0 if /Exit/' infile`

Comment: Sorry man, it was my bad English, I will modify the title.

Comment: No worries. I just modified the solutions to fit the desired requirements. The grep solution is no longer applicable, though.